# How to have user prompt dialogs in Windows 8 metro apps?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I would like to get some user inputs for my app like Name, DOB, etc from a modal window
for this I need a dialog to be displayed which would contain the textboxes and other controls.
 
Normally in WinForms/WPF I would create a class inherited from the Form/Window class and use the Show/ShowDialog method to present the form to the user 
How do I achieve this behavior in Windows 8 metro apps using XAML/C# ?
I have looked at the `MessageDialog` class under the `Windows.UI.Popups` namespace 
but its for showing only message like the classic MessageBox. 
I have looked at another `CoreWindowFlyout` class and also not sure if that can be used for the behavior I am expecting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can simply create a custom `UserControl` with all the required inputs (such as `TextBox`es) and then show it using [`Popup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/BR227842) class.

for example:

```
Popup myPopup = new Popup();
myPopup.Child = new CustomUserControl();
myPopup.IsOpen = true;
```

Answer (score 4):

Following on from the spot on answer from MBZ, have you tried looking at ["**Windows 8 app samples - C#, VB.NET, C++, JavaScript**"](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples) particularly the ["**XAML Popup sample**](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-Popup-sample-5ae00a42)".

Comment: I followed the "XAML Popup sample" link and saw, "This item is not yet published."

Comment: I found this, though: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/custom-control-in-windows-8-apps-using-C-Sharp/

Comment: There is also a "XAML user and custom controls sample" project in the Windows 8.1 Store app samples here: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Windows-8-Modern-Style-App-Samples