# Why is my Windows Store App Popup not popping with my Custom Control?

Tags: popup, windows-store-apps, custom-controls, winrt-xaml, controltemplate

I need to retrieve a string response from the user in my Windows Store App.

Based on what I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12371566/how-to-have-user-prompt-dialogs-in-windows-8-metro-apps) and [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/custom-control-in-windows-8-apps-using-C-Sharp/), I added the class as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26433054/why-am-i-being-told-a-class-does-not-exist-in-my-namespace-when-it-does) with these WinRT XAML controls for now:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text="Enter a name for the Photoset" />
        <TextBox x:Name="txtbxPhotosetName"/>
        <Button Content="Okey dokey" />
    </StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

...and this code to try to invoke that dialog/control and retrieve the entered value:

```
String photosetName = PromptForPhotosetName();
. . .
private string PromptForPhotosetName()
{
    Popup popTart = new Popup();
    var pfpsn = new promptForPhotosetName();
    popTart.Child = pfpsn;
    popTart.IsOpen = true; // <= does not open/dispay
    // neither "pfpsn." nor "popTart.Child." show me what I'd like to see as an available member 
to access, namely "txtbxPhotosetName"
    return "somePhotosetName";
}
```

What do I need to do to make the Popup visible, and then retrieve the text from txtbxPhotosetName?

Comment: I *think* you may need to set the width/height of the Popup, but am not %100 sure. Also, is PromptForPhotosetName being created on the UI thread? We may need to see what is calling PromptForPhotosetName.

Comment: Yes, PromptForPhotosetName() is (eventually) called in response to a button click.

Comment: Can you subscribe to the Opened and Closed events and see if they're called? After that (if it is being called), I wonder if it's being drawn offscreen. Last thing to check is I wonder if the Popup is being destroyed at the end of the method call. Maybe create a Popup backing variable, overwriting the variable, and then calling IsOpen on that value?

Comment: There's got to be an easier way; I can't imagine it's really this involved just to get a string back from the user... After all, you could do it back in the stoned ages with VB using an InputBox! Not that I used VB (I was a Delphi guy), but just to demonstrate how MS made it dead simple in the past.

Comment: Why not use a Flyout instead of a Popup? And have you tried to see if the Popup is being GC'd before getting added to the visual tree?

Comment: I'll czech out the Flyout; if that's easier, I'll definitely go that route.

Comment: I'v e searched around for an example of a flyout where one can get a user's entry, so far to no avail. It boggles my mind that something so essential is so difficult to find. Microsoft does amazing things with their tools, but some of the obvious things that are either not there or hidden underneath submerged volcanoes leaves me shaking my head. Creating the great Ziggurat that is the Windows Store Apps Infrastructure can be compared to man going to the moon - but not affording a handy way to ask a user for a piece of information is akin to not giving the astronaut a cable for his moonwalks.

Comment: What is `promptForPhotosetName`?

Comment: I know it can be deceiving, but I think you mean WinRT XAML (Jupiter?) when you say WPF...

Comment: All you need is a ViewModel. Create a flyout or popup with a textbox. Make the textbox bind using two-way binding to the ViewModel. Retrieve the data out of the ViewModel on button click.

Comment: @FilipSkakun: Yeah WinRT XAML; the only Jupiter I know, though, is a planet. And I can't say I really *know* it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave the popup a nice name and a more typical `TextBlock` content and it just works, no problem there...

```
private void MyButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var popup = new Popup();
    popup.Child = new TextBlock
    {
        FontSize = 72,
        FontFamily = new FontFamily("Consolas"),
        Text = "Hi, I'm a Popup!"
    };
    popup.IsOpen = true; // <= does open/dispay
}
```

Comment: Thanks; now I need to figure out how to get a string inputted by the user from the popup.